# Asp.net multible table access vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

and good day..

I have a code of asp.net in vb.net and work fine for one table but i need to add multible table of( master and dr ) to code the data is the sum from the two table but its different. can anyone help me..thanks advance for all

```
Private Sub getData(ByVal user As String)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim connectionString As String
        Dim connection As OleDbConnection
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Data_For_netConnectionString").ToString
        connection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Dim sqlCmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * from master WHERE UserID = @user", connection)
        sqlCmd.CommandText = _
            "SELECT name, manistry, university, send, card FROM master "
        Dim sqlDa As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user)
        sqlDa.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("manistry").ToString
            TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("university").ToString
            TextBox4.Text = dt.Rows(0)("send").ToString
            TextBox21.Text = dt.Rows(0)("card").ToString
            name.Text = dt.Rows(0)("name").ToString
        End If
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: do you mean to handle 2 result sets from the query?

Comment: yes i need to show data from the two table not one table..thanks for your replay